# Reflector and compiler generated code

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

I have a dll which I disassemble in Reflector, I then generate a class.
The class contains code which does not compile in Visual Studio.

I take it it's leagl IL code, but how can I generate the higher level c# from this.

Seems yield and IEnumerator generate things like `<>1__state;` in the IL which will not compile.

Does anybody know how I can generate a class from reflector that contains this sort of IL?

Is there a reflector addin that will solves this?

```
    private sealed class <Rule_Document>d__0 : IEnumerable<HtmlTag>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<HtmlTag>, IEnumerator, IDisposable
    {
        private int <>1__state;
        private HtmlTag <>2__current;
        public HtmlParser <>4__this;
        private int <>l__initialThreadId;
        public HtmlTag <htmlTag>5__1;
```

Comment: Seems that starting from C# 3.0 you no longer need to obfuscate your code :-)

Comment: @Darin - it is from an iterator block, so 2.0 -but yes; iterators are pretty-much pre-obfuscated.

Comment: @Marc I always think that the names of these compiler generated classes ape the face you make when you look at their code:  d__0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That IL is from an iterator block. Iterators are **horrible** to write manually, and the underlying IL from an iterator block is testament to the reality of what the compiler does for you. Be *grateful* you didn't have to do it yourself!

You could *try* putting that together mainly from the `MoveNext()`, but don't expect miracles. You may also find that renaming the fields (to get rid of things like `<>` prefixes) goes a long way.

However; I *expect* the best thing to do is to understand *what* the code is trying to do, and stop trying to simply <s>steal</s> *borrow* their implementation.

Comment: +1, I agree. If the author of the code wanted other people to read/modify it he would simply release the source code.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Just borrowing to try understand their implementation. I wouldn't steal from Microsoft...

Comment: @user291320 - depending on which piece of code, the debugging symbols may be free available (under license).

Comment: Gravel - I'm trying to understand the HtmlParser class inside the webtestframework.dll. I want to write my own, simple htmlparser. Where would I get the debugging symbols and how would I use them? Can you point me to a link? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).